# Are multiple identical prototypes legal?

Tags: c, prototype, language-lawyer, declaration, c99

The following code does not emit any warnings when compiled with both `gcc` and `clang` on `Linux x64`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(void);

void foo(void);

void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

IMO, it's legal according to the following snippets from C99:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have
>   compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> (...)
>
> For two function
>   types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types
>
> (...)
>
> Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the
>   number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding
>   parameters shall have compatible types.
>
> (...)
>
> Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.

Am I right? I want to make sure it is not UB and that my understanding is correct.

Comment: C standard is C11. Don't use invalid outdated versions of the standard for discussions.

Comment: you could tag it c99 instead of c, if you're really using c99

Comment: `if you're really using c99` - I heard that most compilers still didn't implement all `C99` features let alone `C11` so I wonder what you mean by "really using C99"

Comment: You are allowed to repeat declarations as long as they're equivalent.  For example, given `typedef int int32_2;`, both `int function(int, int);` and `int32_t function(int, int32_t);` are equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: is `equivalent` synonym to `compatible` in C language spec?

Comment: In fact, you can declare the same object or function as many times as you like, provided that the declarations are all *compatible* (as defined by the standard).  Equivalency is not required.

Comment: @user1042840: The C tag is about standard C. Which is undoubtfully C11. And there are still compilers which only support K&R-C. As well as modern compilers like gcc and clang which implement C11 language (they don't provide the library anyway). Note that MS has announced to support C11, but not C99.

Comment: ... which include global variables too. `int i; int i;` is OK.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think it's called `tentative definition`. It's not the same as multiple declarations. I didn't find any discussion about `tentative definition` for functions.

Comment: I will be misusing 'equivalent' if it is a term in the standard.  I was intending to use it colloquially. I won't have time to chase the details through the standard fir a number of hours.

Comment: @Weather-Vane, how is that across compilation units? Multiple storage locations will be allocated that clash at link time?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie within a single compilation unit. Only one of the declarations may have a value defined (even if the same value).

Comment: @user1042840, a "tentative definition" is not the same thing as multiple declarations.  The two can co-occur, or not.  Specifically, "A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*" (C2011, 6.9.2/2).  This has nothing to do with whether declarations are duplicated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I know it's not the same, I just said that :) It was my first thought though.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple identical prototypes are legal, and in fact common, because it is typical in modern C for a function definition to comprise a prototype for that function, and for there also to be a prototype for the function in scope from inclusion of a header file.  That is, given

**foo.h**:

```
void foo(int x);
```

**foo.c**:

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(int x) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

/* ... */
```

there are two identical prototypes for `foo()` in scope in the body of function `foo`'s definition and throughout the rest of the file.  This is fine.

It is also ok to have multiple declarations of the same object or function that are not *identical*, as long as they are *compatible*.  For example, the
declaration

```
void foo();
```

declares `foo` as a function taking unspecified parameters and returning nothing.  This declaration is compatible with the ones already present in `foo.c` and `foo.h`, and it could be added to either one or both of those files with zero additional effect.

And this all applies to objects (variables), too, where some applications are quite common.  For example, if you want to declare a global variable that is accessed from multiple files, then it is common to put a declaration of that variable in a header file.  The C source file containing and the definition of that variable -- which is also a declaration -- typically `#include`s the header, yielding two declarations:

**global.h**:

```
extern int global;
```

**global.c**:

```
#include "global.h"

int global = 42;
```

Or there is the case of forward declaration of compound data types:

```
struct one;

struct two {
    struct one *my_one;
    struct two *next;
};

struct one {
    struct two *my_two;
}
```

Note the multiple compatible, but not identical, declarations of `struct one`.  This particular set of data structures cannot be declared at all without multiple declaration of one of the types.

Comment: Good point about repeated prototype in a definition - I didn't even think about that!

Comment: One more thing - if you have time, can you confirm that my thinking about what parts in `C99` or `C11` standard describe that behavior is correct or should I look for an explanation in a very different part of the standard? Recently I started to enjoy reading official standards, they seem very hard to understand at the beginning the more you read the more you understand.

Comment: I _think_ `void foo() { ... }` as a function _definition_ is the same as `void foo(void) { ... }`  whereas the _declaration_ `void foo()` is not the same as `void foo(void)`. (C99).  Your thoughts or is this outside this post's area?

Comment: @chux, in both C99 and C2011, `foo()` is a function declarator with an empty [parameter] *identifier list*, whereas `foo(void)` is a function declarator with a one-element *parameter type list* (that one element being anonymous).  When these appear as part of a function definition, they have the same meaning with respect to the function's parameters, but only a declarator that includes a parameter type list serves as a prototype (C99 6.9.1/7; C2011 6.9.1/7; and elsewhere), whether in a function definition or not.  Of course, outside a function definition these have different meaning.

Comment: @chux, that also means that a K&R-style definition of a function that takes parameters does not serve as a prototype for that function.  I actually worded my answer rather carefully to be accurate in that respect without delving into the issue.